# Pontryagin's maximum principle for discrete systems: reference request for general case

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, difference-equations, finite-differences

I am reading the articles:

1. *Optimal control for systems described by difference systems*, Hubert Halkin, Advances in Control Systems, Vol 1, Academic Press, New York-London, 1964, Pages 173-196, [MR183564](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=183564).

and the follow up work:

2. *Directional convexity and the maximum principle for discrete systems*, J. M. Holtzman and H. Halkin, SIAM Journal on Control, Vol 4, No 2, 1966, pages 263 - 275, [MR199008](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=199008), [Zbl 0152.09302](https://zbmath.org/0152.09302).

Both articles assume that the function to be maximized is of a simple form:

the $j$-th coordinate $x_j$ of the state vector $x(k)$ (for discrete time $k$).

Bertsekas' *Dynamic Programming and Optimal Control, Vol I*, [MR3644954](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3644954), [Zbl 1375.90299](https://zbmath.org/1375.90299)  provides a proof for a more general cost function (Section 3.3.3:  Minimum Principle for Discrete-Time Problems, page 129) of the form:
$$
J(U) = g_n(x_n) + \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1}g(x_k,u_k)
$$
This result requires the set of controls $U_k$ to be convex.

Reference 2) shows that convexity is too strict a notion and the weaker form of "directional convexity" allows for broader applicability.

I would like to study the general case for the discrete Pontryagin problem using a general cost function of the form:
$$
J(U) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} L(k,x(k),u(k)) + K(n, x_n) \label{1}\tag{$\ast\ast$}
$$
where $L$ is the Lagrangian (as in Liberzon's book *Calculus of Variations and Optimal Control*, [MR2895149](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2895149), [Zbl 1239.49001](https://zbmath.org/1239.49001)).

Can you share references containing proofs for the discrete Pontryagin case that include weaker convexity conditions to handle broader applications **and** incorporate general cost functions as in \eqref{1} above?